# Is switching between Collections worth it?

Tags: java, collections

Java offers us Collections, where every option is best used in a certain scenario.
But what would be a good solution for the combination of following tasks:

1. Quickly iterate through every element in the list (order does not matter)
2. Check if the list contains (a) certain element(s)

Some options that were considered which **may** or **may not** be good practice:

- It could be possible to, for example, first use a `LinkedList`, and
  then convert it to a `HashSet` when the amount of elements
  is unknown in advance (and if duplicates will not be present)
- Pick a solution for one of both tasks and use the same implementation for the other task (if switching to another implementation is not worth it)
- Perhaps some implementation exists that does both (failed to find one)

Is there a 'best' solution to this, and if so, what is it?

EDIT: For potential future visitors, [this page](https://gist.github.com/psayre23/c30a821239f4818b0709) contains many implementations with big O runtimes.

Comment: Note that I removed my comment, because actually, `LinkedHashSet` is best when you want to maintain order. If you want to go through all items without considering order, a `HashSet` is good enough. However, neither can accomodate duplicates.

Comment: Alright, in my specific case, that would be a good solution!

Comment: From my perspective, this is still not quite fleshed out.  You're [motivating two solutions as part of your question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/175248) yet it's wholly unclear what you're actually meant to solve with this.  Can you outline what your actual requirements are?  Why do you need to iterate the collection?  Why do you need to check if an item exists in the collection?  There may be more elegant solutions here.

Comment: I included some options to show that I did some thinking myself, should they be removed?
I'm working on a plugin for a game. Within this game there can be an unknown amount of worlds. The method I'm currently working on, should set the time in a list of worlds to a given value (thus calling a method on every World object). After that, the players in those worlds should receive a message (thus calling methods on those players after checking if they are located in one of the given worlds by looping through all players and checking if the world list contains their current world).

Comment: @DieterNuytemans:  That gives me more context, thanks.  So I was a bit right about the whole XY-problem thing; there's a more elegant solution here.  You're not *really* asking about how to iterate lists; you're asking how you can **publish** messages/events to **subscribed** listeners.

Comment: @Makoto: That's not relevant to the OP's question which is specifically about data structure performance. There's no reason to assume anything about how messages are relayed.

Comment: @jspcal:  If all you're ever taught are loops and collections, every problem becomes one which is solved with just those tools. That doesn't meant that it *must* be solved with those tools, which is why I wanted to learn more as to what the problem really was.  The OP is machinating on a solution and wants validation into the solution, but there is an actual problem in that they want to send messages to a specific object if they have specific state.  That's a solved problem in and of itself and doesn't *necessarily* require iteration, which is why I wanted to know.

Comment: @jspcal:  XY problems can take many forms.  It's important for us to not rush to a solution based on what the OP asks them just because it's something they asked when there could be better solutions out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Quickly iterate through every element in the list (order does not matter)

It the order does not matter, you should go with a `Collection` implementation with a time complexity of `O(n)`, since each of them is implementing `Iterable` and if you want to iterate over each element, you have to visit each element at least once (hence there is nothing better than `O(n)`). Practically, of course, one implementation is more suited compared to another one, since more often you have multiple considerations to take into account.

> Check if the list contains (a) certain element(s)

This is typically the user case for a `Set`, you will have much better time complexity for `contains` operations. One thing to note here is that a `Set` does not have a *predefined order* when iterating over elements. It can change between implementations and it is risky to make assumptions about it.

**Now to your question:**

From my perspective, if you have the choice to choose the data structure of a class yourself, go with the most natural one for that use case. If you can imagine that you have to call `contains` a lot, then a `Set` might be suited for your use case. You can also use a `List` and each time you need to call `contains` (multiple times) you can create a `Set` with all elements from the `List` before. Of course, if you call this method often, it would be *expensive* to create the `Set` for each invocation. You may use a `Set` in the first place.

Your comment stated that you have a world of players and you want to check if a player is part of a certain world object. Since the world *owns* the players, it should also contain a `Collection` of some kind to store them. Now, in this case i would recommend a `Map` with a common identifier of the player as key, and the player itself as value.

```
public class World {

    private Map<String, Player> players = new HashMap<>();

    public Collection<Player> getPlayers() { ... }

    public Optional<Player> getPlayer(String nickname) { ... }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Woops, it's clear to me now. But I meant to ask if I should use different sorts of lists. The answer was that I shouldn't. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: First, `Collection` sure extends `Iterable` and this is what i mean. Of course, each `Collection` implementation has to implement those methods as well. To avoid confusion, i have edited the term.

Comment: This answer doesn't make any sense either. You told the OP to use a `Collection` (specifically a `Set`) but then your example uses a `HashMap` for the very data structure the OP is asking about. Do you know that `HashMap` doesn't implement `Collection`?

Comment: Your original answer stated: *It the order does not matter, it is (theoretically) irrelevant which `Collection` implementation you choose*. That is completely wrong. Obviously each collection has different trade-offs which are *clearly* documented. You should read the Collections documentation.

Answer (score 1):

A [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) can be iterated through quickly and provides efficient lookups.

```
HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<>();
set.add("Hello");

for (Object obj : set) {
    System.out.println(obj);
}

if (set.contains("Hello")) {
    System.out.println("Found");
}
```

Comment: Iteration between a set and a list is still O(n).  Lookups for a hash set are O(1) which are the only real advantage over lists.  Also - you're not guaranteed any specific ordering when iterating over a set unless the set itself is ordered, and hash sets are *not* ordered.

Comment: I take umbrage with the phrase "iterated through quickly" since O(n) is still O(n).

Comment: You clearly didn't read the question. Order isn't important. (Your second comment is irrelevant: you can't iterate over n elements in less than n steps.)

Comment: I'm fine with order not being important.  I'm still harping on the phrase "iterated through quickly", since we have both established that's *not* a thing.  A simple edit would make all of these comments disappear.

Comment: It is a "thing", because not all data structures have that property. Furthermore, HashSet benefits from locality of reference unlike `LinkedList`, which means iteration is faster in practice.

Comment: @Makoto "iterated through quickly" is certainly a thing. E.g. iterating over a LinkedList using a `for` loop with `get(int)` is _O(n^2)_, and is certainly not quick. The word "quickly" is appropriate for iterating the fastest way possible.

Comment: @Andreas:  In the context used, the enhanced-`for` statement leverages the collection's `Iterator` instance.  In this instance, the performance is **identical** and would not rise to a level of measurable difference.  All I'm asking for is that the word "quickly" be removed since the answerer is insistent on using the enhanced-`for`.

Comment: @Makoto: That is false. Did you even read the previous comment? LinkedList traverses random locations in the heap and therefore has poor cache locality.

Comment: Technical discussions are fine, but let's keep the comments civil and professional, folks. Personal attacks, accusations of trolling, etc. are not okay here.